# How can i take N(read from user) number of inputs in an array, in python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to do it like we do in java where we take the number of elements from the user and then declare the  array with the provided size.
ie;
int[] arr=new int[n];

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So are you just getting the size from the users, not the values?  And why do you need to 'declare an array'?  This is Python, not Java.  Usually it is better to create the array or list with the desired values right away, rather than initialize followed by a 'fill'.  But maybe more important - do you want a Python list, or a `numpy` array?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, arrays are called lists and don't have a fixed length. But if you want to create a list with N elements that will all be zero, you could use this code:

```
n = int(input())
lst = []
for x in range(n):
    lst.append(0)
```

Comment: Why not `[0]*n` ?

Comment: OP is clearly a beginner and `[0] * n` is somewhat error-prone. `int`s are primitives so this approach happens to work as expected, but if you were to initialize a list of objects this way (for instance a list of lists), you would see that all its elements are in fact the same object. So I would argue that Daniel Cohen's solution is more beginner-friendly as it keeps them away from shooting themselves in their feet.